# Wkhtmltopdf footer not working on inner pages

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I was trying to show page number at the bottom of each pages using wkhtmltopdf. Tried using both footer html file and footer command. But footer is coming only on my first page (On my cover page).

```
--footer-center "Page [page] of [toPage]"
```

Above given my footer command. What is wrong with this? I have referred **[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135109/wkhtmltopdf-add-content-to-the-bottom-of-the-last-page)** also